# Angular 2.0 (1.5 with ui-router) Component creation

Tags: angular

I am trying to change an Angular 1.x app to use Angular 1.5 components, which is a new feature (question should be relevant for Angular 2.0).

From what I understand I need to create a Root Component which would basically provide the main bootstrapping code for my app, this would obviously need my ui-view so that I can inject the view (state).

I am having an issue trying to understand how detail I should get in creating components.

Lets take a page that is a registration form for example, this is a good example of where I really not 100% sure how to continue.

From what I understand a component should be a self contained component that should work on its own.

So the registration form page would be a component but then I should also create a component for the form and a component for each "special" ui input field i.e. TextBox, Dropdown (assuming these do something special other than the standard html5 elements).

Should I really get down to this level, If I did that the form would need to compose itself with each of the other special components. This would mean the form could be reused and show with different elements and the same goes the for ui elements, they could be reused in other places. Should I be dropping down to this level ?

The other thing that has me a little confused is dependencies (not injection), So if form as a dependency on 3 x special combobox and 1 x of my special textbox then I would need to place these items inside IT'S template. Although now this component isn't  a self contained component as it has dependencies on other components to build itself.

Of course the UI elements (my special textbox, special combobox) would be self contained.

So my question is, is this acceptable? I don't see any other way round it. Certainly some higher components will have dependencies on other components right ? Otherwise my form could never compose itself.

Am I missing something here ? Is there an alternative to placing other components inside the templates ?

I suppose I could use a child state for each component in the form, but this just FEELS WRONG and although this would remove the component tags from the higher component, I would still need to have NAMED ui-views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I understand I need to create a Root Component which would basically provide the main bootstrapping code for my app, this would obviously need my ui-view so that I can inject the view (state).

In Angular2 there is a root component that wraps a whole Angular2 application. You can have multiple Angular2 application on a single page. Each application is bootstrapped individually with it's own root component. The application consists of it view and the HTML, components and directives added to it.

> From what I understand a component should be a self contained component that should work on its own.

Not sure what you mean by "self contained". A component like a class, should do one thing and do it well. 
If a component is intended to be used only in conjunction with a specific other component this is fine as well.

For example when you have menu item component that only works with your custom menu component. Of course it's better to have a menu item that can work in other menu components, but when your menu component can provide special features when used with a customized menu item component, than that's perfectly valid.

> So the registration form page would be a component but then I should also create a component for the form and a component for each "special" ui input field i.e. TextBox, Dropdown (assuming these do something special other than the standard html5 elements).

If you make Angular components for each UI elements, the big advantage is that you can reuse these components in other components and applications. 
This also aligns well with what I said above. A component should do one thing and do it well. Then compose other components and applications from your components.

> Should I really get down to this level, If I did that the form would need to compose itself with each of the other special components. This would mean the form could be reused and show with different elements and the same goes the for ui elements, they could be reused in other places. Should I be dropping down to this level ?

I don't think it's common to build generic form components but it can be done and I'm certain there are situations where this makes perfect sense.  Angular2 components also support transclusion. You could create a form component that contains a border and a submit button and an area where it displays validation errors and a `<ng-content></ng-content>` marker where children are laid out.

```
<my-form>
  <my-dropdown label="gender" [data]="genderList" [(ngModel)]="gender"></my-dropdown>
  <my-date label="birth date" [(ngModel)]="birthDate"><my-date>
</my-form>
```

> The other thing that has me a little confused is dependencies (not injection), So if form as a dependency on 3 x special combobox and 1 x of my special textbox then I would need to place these items inside IT'S template. Although now this component isn't a self contained component as it has dependencies on other components to build itself.

In my above example the `<my-form>` component doesn't need to have any knowledge about `<my-dropdown>` or `<my-date>`, only the component that uses `<my-form>`, `<my-dropdown>`, or `<my-date>` needs to list them in `directives: [MyForm, MyDropdown, MyDate]`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Reading below, I think I am starting to understand it now. So I was classing the my-dropdownm my-other-control as components and these are infact not components but they are directives. Seems like there is a fine line between components and directives.

Comment: Can you try to explain the differences between components vs directives. So directives are UI controls (normally)  and components are are like containers for ui components. So yep this would be true, the my-dropdown and my-form wouldn't need to know about each other because the component composes them right ?

Comment: What sort of level do I need to drop down to, can you give some examples. So a component could be a full page right ? But also could be just part of a page? If it makes sense to reuse it then I componentize it ??

Comment: Actually `my-dropdown` and `my-other-control` are components. Components **are** directives. Components in addition to directives have a view (HTML content) while directives are code-only.

Comment: If it needs to display something (render something in the DOM) then it's a component. A component can render plain HTML or other components that render HTML. Everyting visible is a component and components are (usually) compositions of other components (except the leaf nodes of course).

Comment: Directives are usually used to add non-visible behavior to other elements and components.

Comment: Great. Nearly there now then ! Only problem is that I don't fully understand your last statement. "In my above example the <my-form> component doesn't need to have any knowledge about <my-dropdown> or <my-date>, only the component that uses <my-form>, <my-dropdown>, or <my-date> needs to list them in directives: [MyForm, MyDropdown, MyDate]."

Comment: But wouldn't my-form would  have knowledge of my-dropdown and my-date - right ?

Comment: How could you design my-form so that it would have children BUT it wouldn't physically have this information in IT's HTML VIEW?

Comment: That depends on how you design `my-form`. If `foo-comp` has a template like `<my-form><my-dropdown></my-dropdown><my-form>` then `foo-comp` needs to provide `my-dropdown`. When then `my-form` has a template like `<ng-content></ng-content>` then ´my-dropdown` is displayed as a child of `my-form` but it is actually only a direct dependency of `foo-comp`. You might to interact in some between `my-form` and its projected content `my-dropdown`, which might require `my-form` to know something about it. But it's not necessary by default.

Comment: If a component has a `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag in it's template, than anything that is passed as child content is displayed instead of `<ng-content>`. You can have multiple `<ng-content>` with selectors that display only the part of the passed child content that match the selector `<h1><ng-content select=".header"></content></h1><div><ng-content><ng-content></div>` (where the 2nd ng-content displays the elements that don't match the selector)